# Are the plots in rstudio saved into an index?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a function that creates many plots in RStudio. I'd like to flick to the first plot that comes out of the function without having to page through every plot one at a time, with the right/left arrows.

What're the options for scrolling through the plots in R Studio. Ideally, I'd be able to execute plot[1] and start from the beginning and the flip through the plots. Is it possible to go to the beginning of the plot cue?

The part that makes me hopeful, and the reason i asked, is that I occasionally get a server error that reads "Server Error: Invalid Plot Index"

Here's a reproducible example

```
library('mlbench')
data(BostonHousing)
Boston <- BostonHousing

ExploreNumeric <- function(df){
  num_vars <- which(sapply(df, is.numeric))
  X <- df[names(num_vars)]
  for (i in 1:length(names(num_vars))){
    Y <- as.data.frame(X[i])
    Z <- colnames(Y)
    print(summary(Y))
    Q <- quartiles(Y)
    print(Q[1])
    S <- c(sapply(Y,mean),sapply(Y,sd),kurtosis(Y),skewness(Y))
    S <- round(S,2)
    R <- c("mean","stdev","kurtosis","skewness")
    print(rbind(R,S))
    colnames(Y) <- "col"
    Hist <- ggplot(Y,aes(col)) + geom_histogram()
    Dens <- ggplot(Y,aes(col)) + geom_density()
    Box <- ggplot(Y,aes("col",col)) + geom_boxplot() 
    Scatter <- ggplot(Y,aes(seq_along(col),col)) + geom_point()
    G <- ggarrange(Hist,Dens,Box,Scatter, ncol=2,nrow=2)
    print(annotate_figure(G, top=Z))
  }
}

ExploreNumeric(Boston)
```

My goal is to be able to flick back to the first chart created by the function.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example - for example if you are creating a model and want to plot it - then the plot(model) function actually has 5 plots which you can index e.g. plot(model,1) shows residuals of a model etc

Comment: done, thanks for the reminder

Comment: Does it have to be the RStudio plot device? Personally, I'd plot to a file, but you could also use `windows(record = TRUE)` and access `.SavedPlots[1]`. However, I don't think you can open the RStudioGD device with recording enabled.